# A dictionary that systematizes commonly accepted combinations of words

Tags: dictionaries, collocation

Where can I find a dictionary that contains words along with their commonly accepted "neighbors"?

I had one, but it's not for English language. The structure of this dictionary is the following. Take a noun in this dictionary. Along with its brief definition, the dictionary shows what adjectives, verbs, and other parts of speech are appropriate to use with this noun.

E.g., a "day." Possible adjectives: "sunny," "long," "bad," etc. Verbs: "spend," "waste," etc. And so forth for many instances. Quite a handy thing for writing.

What English dictionaries offer similar capacities?

PS: It's not about simple collocations or corpuses and ngrams that don't differentiate parts of speech, like [Corpus Concordance English](http://www.lextutor.ca/concordancers/concord_e.html). It's important to have this part-of-speech distinction.

**UPDATE:**

Brief list of dictionaries from the answers:

- [Online version](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/) of Oxford Collocation Dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OXFORD COLLOCATIONS DICTIONARY FOR STUDENTS OF ENGLISH**
In Indian English one can see such mistakes as 'I *did a mistake* when I wrote the letter'. It is because they do not know that *did* does not collocate with *mistake* and that the word which collocates with *mistake* is *made*. Always say *make a mistake*, not *do a mistake*. It is also correct if you use *commit a mistake*. Such mistakes can be avoided if you have a copy of **OXFORD COLLOCATIONS DICTIONARY FOR STUDENTS OF ENGLISH** at your elbow. I assure you that it is an excellent dictionary. It may be available all over the world.

Comment: I think it's a great tool indeed. Personally, I check _wrong_ collocations at Google News/Books with relevant filters, like [this one](http://www.google.com/search?tbs=bks:1&q=%22did+a+mistake%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2000%2Ccd_max%3A2099&tbm=bks&qscrl=1). Oxford Collocations Dictionary is definitely one of the options, as I now see. Maybe others will suggest more dictionaries like this.

Comment: In the event anyone can't find, or can't afford a paper resource like that, they could always turn to Google Books and search for [*"made a mistake"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22made+a+mistake%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Then compare the 30 million results from that search term with 170 thousand for *"committed a mistake"*, and a mere 4540 for *"did a mistake"*. Save your money *and* save trees! Use online resources!

Answer (score 0):

MacMillan Collocations Dictionary can also be used for the very same purpose. However, a learner may find what Mr Abootty suggested to be more useful.